# Plotting with Xgraph in tcl

Tags: tcl, ns2

I am using the following command to read the data from a text file with two variable as:

```
0 4
1 5
3 7
```

.. so on.

```
exec xgraph data.txt -t "K vs Pow data" -x "Value of K" -y "Value of Pow" -m
```

But my xgraph is not showing any points. All I can see is both the axis and legend on the right side. Is there a option I have to add to start showing the line graph or if possible the points on the grid.

Comment: There seem to be _two_ different programs called `xgraph` about…

Answer (score 1):

use -P option to plot points.for example, xgraph -P filename

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: to show points with line graph
 
 xgraph filename  -P

and just for line graph:
xgraph filename -geometry 800*400